# status of getting PGI compiler

Tags: pgi

I used to freely download the community version of the PGI compiler, which for however many years seemed to be one version older than the professional version.  As the professional version updated to a new version, that old version became the freely available "community" version.

Can someone tell me, plainly, what is going on now?

I've made an account, did not succeed in finding out how i get it now.  I did not find a price list or any indication of *go here and pay us money*.  I need to understand what's going on, as I relied on it to provide its libraries in order to run other software we paid for that was pgi compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PGI was re-branded to be the NVIDIA HPC Compiler and now part the the NVHPC SDK which is available at https://developer.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk

> I used to freely download the community version of the PGI compiler,
> which for however many years seemed to be one version older than the
> professional version. As the professional version updated to a new
> version, that old version became the freely available "community"
> version.

This isn't quite accurate.  The complier packages for both the Community and Professional Editions were exactly the same.  The Community Edition was not an older release.  The difference was that Professional Edition licenses holder were provided email support as well as intermediate releases, while the Community Edition users were provided support only via the PGI User Forums with releases made available twice a year.

With the new NVHPC SDK, all releases are now available at no-cost.  For-fee email support is available if needed.   Though free support is still available through the User Forums which have been moved to NVIDIA's Developer forums:  https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/accelerated-computing/hpc-compilers/299/l/latest which I moderate.  Though I and others check StackOverflow as well, so feel free to ask questions here and we'll do our best to answer.